# Python quotation mark canceler algorithm

Tags: python

```
i = 1
def textconverter(t,color='black'):
    #Magically change all quotation marks (') to (\')
    cwprint(t,color)
def cwprint(t,color='black'):
    global i
    exec('label%d = Label(cw,text=\''%i+t+'\',fg=color).grid(row='+str(i)+')')
    i += 1
textconverter('test')
```

I am building a small chat program to experiment with the Tkinter and socket libraries, but however I ran into this problem: I want to print a value (text which is sent by the user) on the screen using a label.

Everything goes alright untill the user inputs a string including a quotation mark. For example: 'Don't do that'

Python will think that the string is 'Don' and doesn't recognise the 't do that' part.
Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

btw: cwprint stands for print on chat window

Comment: WHY do you use `exec` for creating an instance of `Label`?

Comment: I am calling the function multiple times, so I want to get label1 = (...) label2 = (...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we got here a X-Y-problem par excellence. Don't use `exec` to create sequential variable names. Use a list instead:

```
i = 1
def cwprint(t,labels,color='black'):
    global i
    text = '{} {}'.format(i, t)
    labels.append (Label(cw,text=text,fg=color).grid(row=i))
    i += 1

labels = []
cwprint ('Hello', labels)
cwprint ('World', labels)
```

No need for `exec` or for string escaping.